# Dynamically get the maximum and minimum allowable value for a number column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Suppose  a column called `money`, which is `NOT NULL` and its type is NUMBER(x,y) .There is no constraint on this column.

I want to sort this `money` column according to this sequence , +ve > -ve > 0 , so my plan is to decode the 0 value to the minimum allowable  value that the money column can hold in the order by clause, like `select * from tableXXX order by decode(money, 0 , allowableMnimumValueForMoneyColumn , money) desc` . I just wonder if it is possible to get the minimum  allowable value for the money column dynamically.

How can I get the  maximum and minimum allowable  value for a column ?  Does oracle has the implicit variables to do it?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're after, like sample data?

Comment: @OMG Ponies  , I have updated my question.Hope it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the records whose value for `money` = 0 appear last.

If this is the case you would go by such an order clause:

```
order by 
case when money = 0 then 0
                    else 1 
end desc,
money desc
```

With a working example, that would be

```
create table tq84_order_by (
  txt   varchar2(10),
  money number not null
);

insert into tq84_order_by values ('aaa', 0);
insert into tq84_order_by values ('bbb', 2);
insert into tq84_order_by values ('ccc',-3);
insert into tq84_order_by values ('ddd', 4);
insert into tq84_order_by values ('eee', 1);

select * from tq84_order_by
order by 
case when money = 0 then 0
                    else 1 
                    end desc,
                    money desc;
```

resulting in

```
TXT             MONEY
---------- ----------
ddd                 4
bbb                 2
eee                 1
ccc                -3
aaa                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to know the minimum value. You can treat NULL as the minimum value:

```
... ORDER BY decode(money, 0, NULL, money) NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a check constraint on the column:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (MONEY NUMBER(14,2) NOT NULL)
/

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD
  CONSTRAINT MONEY_VALID CHECK (( MONEY > 100 AND MONEY < 5000))
/

-- This fails
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (20);

-- This works
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (110);
```

Comment: Stupid firewall doesn't let me post SQL because it thinks I'm doing a SQL injection attack.  Maybe someone can fix the above.